# Problem with webscraping using rvest and sapply, "`x` must be a string of length 1"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, sapply

I am new to webscraping and R and trying to webscrape the names of all Professors of a faculty with the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://wiso.uni-koeln.de/de/fakultaet/fakultaetsbereiche"
page = read_html(link)

fac_area = page %>% html_nodes("#subnavigation a") %>% html_text()
link_area = page %>% html_nodes("#subnavigation a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://wiso.uni-koeln.de/de/fakultaet/fakultaetsbereiche", ., sep= "")

Prof = function(link_areas){
  area = read_html(link_area)
  chair_prof = area %>% html_nodes (".uzk15__standard_h3") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(chair_prof)
}

profs = sapply(link_area, FUN = Prof, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

But I get the Error:

> "`x` must be a string of length 1"

I don't understand if this error is due to a mistake in the function or in `sapply`, the function itself does not give me an error message and the `link_area` list is excactly what I would want it to be.

Comment: you'd better use another name for parameter of you function .. it's misleading .. and the parameter name is "link_aeras", but in the function you use "link_aera" ..

Comment: Did you check similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/62492770/18667225 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two minor errors.

First, your `link_area` pasted too much into the URLs. The line should have been:

```
link_area = page %>% html_nodes("#subnavigation a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://wiso.uni-koeln.de", ., sep= "")
```

(Otherwise the URLs lead to a 404 error which is why you had the error message)

Secondly, in the function `Profs`, the first line had a typo (`link_area` even though it should have been `link_areas`).

So, the full code should be:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://wiso.uni-koeln.de/de/fakultaet/fakultaetsbereiche"
page = read_html(link)

fac_area = page %>% html_nodes("#subnavigation a") %>% html_text()
link_area = page %>% html_nodes("#subnavigation a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://wiso.uni-koeln.de", ., sep= "")
# ^^^ note the shortened URL in the paste()-function

Prof = function(link_areas){
  area = read_html(link_areas) # <---- note there was a typo here
  chair_prof = area %>% html_nodes (".uzk15__standard_h3") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(chair_prof)
}

profs = sapply(link_area, FUN = Prof, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so focused on the ending of the URL (which were correct) that I didn't notice the mistakes within the URL text!